# Linking a bookmark to an image in a different file, HTML

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html

So, I have this for the image:

```
<p class="b1">
    <img id="cakes" src="~/images/cakesBanner.png" alt="cakes">
</p>
```

and in a separate file I have this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#cakes">Cakes</a></li>
```

But instead of the button scrolling to the bookmark, it navigates to 
    `.../Views/Home/Index.cshtml#cakes`

New to HTML and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Html.ActionLink` helper method. It will generate the proper link for you. So, instead of:

```
<a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#cakes">Cakes</a>
```

use:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Cakes",
    actionName: "Index",
    controllerName: "Home",
    protocol: null,
    hostName: null,
    fragment: "cakes",
    routeValues: null,
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

This will generate:

```
<a href="/Home/Index#cakes">Cakes</a>
```

Notice, that the proper URL is `/Home/Index` and not `~/View/...`.

Comment: I copied and pasted your suggestion but I'm getting an error: "The best overload for 'ActionLink' does not have a parameter named 'hostName'". I have no idea what this means.

Comment: What happens if you just remove this line `hostName: null,` ??

Comment: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'hostName' of 'lHtmlHelper.ActionLink(string,string,string,string,string,string,object,object)'